# Issues with border color on samsung devices

Tags: android, border

I have a list view in which i am inserting some images but the problem is whenever i run this code on any Samsung phone the border  color behaves weird, sometimes the border is shown and sometimes not. But this code runs perfectly in my Motorola XT1022.
Please help me.

Below is the code of each item in the list view

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="titlegdfiwughfiwue"
    android:textColor="#ffffa51d"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="address"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serviceType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="serviceType"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/address"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/address"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/address"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@drawable/t"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
    android:width="1dip"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:color="#5e7974"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="3px" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am having problem with the last Image View. Sometimes the border is there and sometimes not.Please help me.

Comment: Really?? No one had this issue?

Comment: Still waiting for someone to answer.